# Code chef Beginner (lead game)

Tags: java

> The Siruseri Sports Club organises an annual billiards game where the top two players of Siruseri play against each other. The Manager of Siruseri Sports Club decided to add his own twist. In his version, at the end of each round the leader and her current lead are calculated. Once all the rounds are over the player who had the maximum lead at the end of any round in the game is declared the winner.
>
> The total scores of both players, the leader and the lead after each round for this game is given below:
>
> ```
> Round          Player 1          Player 2     Leader     Lead
>   1               140                82       Player 1     58
>   2               229               216       Player 1     13
>   3               319               326       Player 2      7
>   4               431               432       Player 2      1
>   5               519               522       Player 2      3
> ```
>
> The winner of this game is Player 1 as he had the maximum lead (58 at the end of round 1) during the game.
>   Your task is to help the Manager find the winner and the winning lead. You may assume That is, there are no ties.
>
> Input
>   The first line of the input will contain a single integer N (N ≤ 10000) indicating the number of rounds in the game. Lines 2,3,...,N+1 describe the scores of the two players in the N rounds. Line i+1 contains two integer Si and Ti, the scores of the Player 1 and 2 respectively, in round i. You may assume that 1 ≤ Si ≤ 1000 and 1 ≤ Ti ≤ 1000.
>
> Output
>   Your output must consist of a single line containing two integers W and L, where W is 1 or 2 and indicates the winner and L is the maximum lead attained by the winner.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class billardsDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rounds = in.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        int lead = 0;
        int flag = 0;
        while (i < rounds) {
            int score1 = in.nextInt();
            int score2 = in.nextInt();
            if (score1 > score2 && score1 - score2 > lead) {
                flag = 1;
                lead = score1 - score2;
            } else if (score2 > score1 && score2 - score1 > lead) {
                flag = 2;
                lead = score2 - score1;
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(flag +" "+ lead);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

I am getting the right output in eclipse, but code chef says wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your input doesn't total the scores, but replace the last score with the new scan.

I would suggest declaring the variable `score1` and `score2` before the loop and change the code inside the loop to:

```
score1 += in.nextInt();
```

which is equal to

```
score1 = score1 + in.nextInt();
```

The same goes for `score2`, of course.

See this accepted solution on their website for a complete code:

https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/8684978

//edit: I think you should also add a space character between the integers in the output. Otherwise the output will be "158" instead of "1 58".

Comment: If you're stuck like this, you can always click the button "All Submissions" on the page of the problem and sort for an accepted answer in your language. Also, if you scroll down to "Editorial" on the page of the problem, there is also a link to further explanation. In this case, I find the explanation from codechef somewhat misleading and there seem to be quite some irritations about this task. Not sure why he would use arrays or the modulus for this task...

Comment: yeah got it, the question hasnt been explained properly.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that immediately stands out is your `println` statement at the end. You're printing one integer instead of two since `flag` and `lead` get combined. The correct code should be:

```
System.out.println(flag + " " + lead);
```

In my opinion, you should try to parse the input line by line as intended, not `nextInt` by `nextInt` as this might lead to unknown complications. You should read the whole line, then tokenize it and get the first two integers.

Also, online judges are usually very finicky about class and method names so make sure you name your class how they want you to (for example on *HackerRank* your class must be named `Solution` for the code to work).

Finally, how do you handle ties in the lead? In your problem statement it says there are no ties but does this mean no ties in the round or no ties in the leads as well? What I mean is this: suppose player 1 wins the first round with a lead of 1. Then player 2 wins the second round also with a lead of 1. What should your flag be, 1 or 2?

Comment: @vojta so he prints flag+""+lead. If flag is 1 and lead is 3 lets say, the output printed will be 13. When the judge tries to parse his output, it won't parse 1 & 3 but rather 13. There needs to be a space between the 1 and the 3 for it to constitute as two different integers as per his output constraint.

Comment: @EugenHotaj Sorry, my blindness... You are absolutely right. I will upvote your answer as soon as I can. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you solve it this way? Please explain. And is it a problem with code chef of with your programming?

My way of solving would be this:

1. create helper class that hold the matches, with the values:
   Player1 score, Player2 score, difference in score.
2. make an array of said matches and iterate thou them to find the
   largest  value.
3. now you have the winning match, go and find the player who won it.
4. Print the winning player and the points.

Comment: Their solution is essentially doing your steps 2-4 without having to use an intermediate array (= less memory used). There is no reason to keep track of all scores in an array. You only need to keep track of the current leader / leading score. Also online judges are usually limited to a single class so you usually can't use a helper class.

Comment: Yea, thank you pointing that out. If you can use a single class, that would have to be it then. Not sure why you would want to use Java in that case, being very OO.